# Data rate/Line rate on the Ethernet interface

Tags: ethernet, rate, transmission

I got a question about the data rate of the ethernet interface and hope someone can give me some hints on that.

I know the calculation method of the PCIe interface, for example, PCIe Gen3 X1 lane:
The data rate of single-lane should be

```
8 Gb/s (Gen3 line rate) * 2 (TX/RX, full-duplex) / 8 (to Byte) = 2 GB/s
```

(128/130 encoding is ignored)
So, how do we calculate the data rate of an ethernet interface?
Take 1000base-T for example, we have 4 twisted pairs, to sum up to 1Gb data rate.

So one pair should provide a 250Mb data rate. It’s full-duplex so TX/RX provides 125Mb each at the same time. With that being said, the “line rate” of a 1000base-T interface is 125MHz (125Mb).

Do I understand it correctly about the speedrunning on the ethernet interface?

Comment: The data rate where on the Ethernet interface? Towards the host? On the MDI? Raw bit rate? Symbol rate? Btw, Gigabit Ethernet runs 1 Gbit/s each way full-duplex, so its 250 Mbit/s per lane each way for 1000BASE-T.

Comment: So basically the "1 Gbit/s" means only one way of the MDI interface? if we count the total throughput, it shall be 2 Gbit/s since it's full-duplex, is that correct? And yes, I mean "raw bit rate".

Comment: The nominal rate of 1 Gbit/s is at the top of the physical layer. It includes preamble, SOF and IPG, but excludes all PHY-specific line encoding (PCS and PMA). It's defined where all same-speed PHYs are exactly the same. At the MDI (bottom of L1), you've got fully encoded streams, in the simplest case 1000BASE-X with 1.25 Gbit/s duplex (with 8b10b PCS code). If you insist to add both ways it's 2 Gbit/s w/o and 2.5 Gbit/s w/ PCS encoding for -X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do we calculate the data rate of an ethernet interface?

Ethernet's nominal bit rate is generally defined at the top of the physical layer (L1).  It includes preamble, SOF and IPG, but excludes all PHY-specific line encoding (PCS and PMA).

This is done to make all PHY variants of the same speed 100% compatible with each other. You can convert 1000BASE-T to 1000BASE-LX to 1000BASE-SX and back to 1000BASE-T without any buffer drops.

> It’s full-duplex so TX/RX provides 125Mb each at the same time.

No - the nominal bitrate runs each direction, simultaneously for full duplex links. Each 1000BASE-T lane transports 250 Mbit/s worth of "user" data.

> With that being said, the “line rate” of a 1000base-T interface is 125MHz (125Mb).

Since the line rate is (usually) the PHY rate it's 1000 MBit/s, four lanes of 250 Mbit/s each.

1000BASE-T does use a *symbol rate* of 125 MBaud since its PAM-5 modulation transports more than two bits per symbol. You might think that PAM-4 with exactly two bits would be sufficient, but the line code overhead eats up the rest. 1000BASE-T is already quite complex, it uses two-dimensional Trellis modulation plus scrambling to get across the wire (to produce a self-clocking signal, improve the signal/noise ratio and eliminate excess DC).

The 1000BASE-X PHYs for fiber are much simpler. The PCS uses 8b10b to produce a binary stream of 1.25 GBd that can be directly used to modulate the laser.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zac! It helps!  I have an extensional question about the difference between 1000BASE-T and 1000BASE-X. to my understanding, the reason why we need extra PHY chip outside the MAC controller for 1000BASE-T is that the coding and modulation stuff are so complicated, which needs a specific PHY chip to deal with those things. For 1000BASE-X, since it's transmitted by optics, it doesn't need such complicate method to "assemble" the data in order to "adapt" the poor media like copper, it can just use the SERDES interface for the optical module to transmit. Not sure if that's correct.

Comment: One thing that confuses me is that, many MAC controller uses SGMII to connect to an external PHY chip for 1000BASE-T application, while 1000BASE-X uses SERDES interface for SFP optical modules. Some documents specify that the difference between the SGMII and SERDES interface is the Auto-negotiation. Why don't we just use SGMII for both connection to the PHY chip, and to the optical modules?     And the reason why we can directly use a SERDES to transmit the data is that optic media is much "cleaner" than copper media, so we don't have to do the "noise improvement" things as BASE-T, right?

Comment: May I have the assumption that, since it's simpler, the PCA/PMA for BASE-X are normally built-in with the MAC controller, while BASE-T needs the external PHY chip for the complicated PCS/PMA circuitry?

Comment: Each medium requires a suitable modulation scheme. The key is modularity: you can pair a Gigabit MAC with many different PHYs, creating a multitude of solutions. Modular transceivers make the PHY even field-configurable.

Comment: An SFP module is not a complete PHY, it's (more or less) just the lowest sublayer (PMD). PCS and PMA still sit in the switch/NIC itself and these use SGMII or similar upwards. Autonegotiation is also a PHY function, not in the transceiver itself.

Comment: Twisted pair requires more elaborate encoding because of the worse SNR but also because of the much worse frequency response/attenuation of copper. Running 1+ GHz over copper is expensive and delicate (see Cat-8), while fiber is very OK with 50 GHz.over 10 km.